# Why SingleOrDefault result TOP(2) in SQL?

Tags: entity-framework, t-sql

I am using EF4.0, and I wrote a query:

```
var query = context.Post.Where(p => p.Id == postId).SingleOrDefault();
```

I need only One post from this query. I thought SingleOrDefault() will generate "SELECT TOP(1) ...", but when I look into SQL Profiler, It was:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (2) 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], 
[Extent1].[Slug] AS [Slug], 
[Extent1].[PubDate] AS [PubDate], 
[Extent1].[PostContent] AS [PostContent], 
[Extent1].[Author] AS [Author], 
[Extent1].[CommentEnabled] AS [CommentEnabled], 
[Extent1].[AttachmentId] AS [AttachmentId], 
[Extent1].[IsPublished] AS [IsPublished], 
[Extent1].[Hits] AS [Hits], 
[Extent1].[CategoryId] AS [CategoryId]
FROM [dbo].[Post] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 uniqueidentifier',@p__linq__0='ECD9F3BE-3CA9-462E-AE79-2B28C8A16E32'
```

I wonder why EF result in SELECT TOP (2)? I only need one post.

Comment: And you could use:
`var query = context.Post.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == postId);`

Comment: We're using NHibernate, which I expected to do this, but it doesn't... It selects everything... Grrrrr...

Answer (score 90, accepted):

It selects top 2 so that if there are actually 2 or more than 2 records in the database, an exception would be thrown. If it only selects top 1 there would be no way to error out.

Answer (score 41):

By asking for the `SingleOrDefault` of a sequence, you are asking for this behaviour:

- if the sequence has exactly `0` elements, return the `default` for the sequence's element type
- if the sequence has exactly `1` element, return the element
- if the sequence has more than `1` element, throw

Doing a `TOP (1)` would empower the first two parts of this, but not the third. Only by doing a `TOP (2)` can we differentiate between exactly `1` record and more than `1` record.

If you *don't* want or need the third part of the above behviour, instead use `FirstOrDefault`.